# View PDF viewing option in LED

Tags: led-editor

I have LED editor of Latex, which I downloaded here http://www.latexeditor.org/download_main.html
I would like to know how can I enable its PDF viewing option. I want to type and then compile and then see what I type not like going to the actual file and check every time to see what happened. Some thing shows me what I am writing after each compile.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! My impression is that LEd isn't the best choice, as its maintenance has been absent for five years. I believe you are best served with a multiplatform editor such as TeXStudio, Texmaker or TeXworks, that are more actively developed.